# What is LUIS "Speech Requests"?

Tags: nlp, azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

The LUIS pricing page states

> Standard-Web/Container
>   Text Requests €1.265 per 1,000 transactions
>   Speech Requests €4.639 per 1,000 transactions

"https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/cognitive-services/language-understanding-intelligent-services/"

What does "speech requests" refer to?

Does this mean it's possible to send audio to LUIS instead of text? I can find only API and SDK methods accepting text input. Where is the corresponding documenation?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible as per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/how-to-recognize-intents-from-speech-csharp#luis-and-speech) where you can find a tutorial that walks you through the necessary steps to use the [Speech SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/speech-sdk) to develop a C# console application that derives intents from user utterances through your device's microphone.

> LUIS integrates with the Speech Services to recognize intents from
>   speech. You don't need a Speech Services subscription, just LUIS.

The price corresponding to the "Speech Requests" feature is for the speech transcriptions you do using LUIS.

The [Speech SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/speech-sdk) is also available in many languages and for many platforms.

Comment: Thanks for that comment, but I have my doubts. According to the pricing page, the "speech requests" should not be available with a free subscription tier: ("Free Tier includes only text as an input."), but the functionality you mention is ("You can use the free subscription tier for this tutorial")

Comment: Also I would be wondering, why the more expensive service delivers less data. With the mentioned Speech SDK I was never able to extract multiple intent predictions or entity roles.

Comment: Yes, the Free Tier of LUIS includes only text as input, but you can use the Standard Tier with the [free subscription](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/) as it provides you with $200 credit for free to explore any Azure service for 30 days!

Comment: In terms of less data from speech requests, that is probably because a speech request transaction is an utterance with query length up to 15 seconds long only

Comment: The 15 seconds limitation doesn't really explain, why roles or secondary intent predictions aren't included. I'd love to send audio to LUIS, since I believe it will be faster than sending subsequent requests to STT and Luis. But the lack of roles and secondary predictions prevents that. Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: I meant that maybe you can't fit in as many words in one 15 seconds utterance, which is why you might want to use the continuous recognition mode `StartContinuousRecognitionAsync()` and `StopContinuousRecognitionAsync()` instead of the single-shot recognition mode `RecognizeOnceAsync()`